# asp.net multipline textbox validation

Tags: asp.net, validation

i need to allow 300 words or less(not characters) in asp.net multiline textbox.
i know that RegularExpressionValidator can be used but what will be ValidationExpression for 300 words?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `CustomValidator`, then in the `ServerValidate` event you could check the words (being defined by having a space between).

```
protected void ServerValidation(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    args.IsValid = myTextBox.Text.Split(" ").Length > 300;
}
```

Comment: first one is not working. for testing purpose i used this ValidationExpression="^\s*([^\s]\s*){1,10}$" and just entered "testing testing" in multiline textbox. it shows validation error

Comment: @SAK It shows the validation error because you entered more than 10 characters which is highlighted as the maximum in the regex...

Comment: but what i need is 10 words and not 10 characters

Comment: Aaah, sorry I misread. Check out my new answer. This is assuming that words are defined as characters having spaces between.